# Flutter Stack with CircularProgressIndicator and GridView widgets, does nor work propertly

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Stack widget as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = StringsES.title_meter_list_screen;
    _context = context;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: appbar,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              primary: false,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: _buildWidgetList(),
            ),

            Align(
                child: _progressBarWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```

And the _progressBarWidget is the following:

```
  Widget _progressBarWidget() {
return (_isProgressBarVisible)
    ? CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 4.0, )
    : Container();
```

}

In this way, the CircularProgressIndicator Widget is displayed behind the GridView, and I want it to appear in front of the GridView.
If I change my code and replace the CircularProgressIndicator with a simple text widget, it works correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using FutureBuilder? If you can convert your logic to work with a FutureBuilder then it is a lot easier to display CircularProgressIndicator. https://medium.com/@jimmyhott/using-futurebuilder-to-create-a-better-widget-4c7d4f52a329

Comment: Let me see... I 'm going to try.